# How to link the CSS file to HTML in GWT

Tags: html, css, gwt

In my GWT application on client side I am generating a string that contains HTML content and passing it to a function which opens it in new tab. I have written a CSS file to style the HTML content and given a link to it. But my HTML file is not getting styled.

```
public void writeHtml(){
    StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
    html.append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    html.append("<html lang=\"en\">");
    html.append("<head>");
    html.append("<title>Hello World</title>");
    html.append("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
                "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n");

    html.append("<link href=\"StyleSheet.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">");

    html.append("</head>");
    html.append("<body>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<h1>This is a heading</h1>\n" +
                "<p>This is a paragraph.</p>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>");
    openPrintWindow(html.toString());
}

public native void openPrintWindow(String contents) /*-{
    var printWindow = window.open("", "PrintWin", false);
    printWindow.document.open("text/html","replace");
    if (printWindow && printWindow.top) {
        printWindow.document.write(contents);

    } else {
        alert("The print feature works by opening a popup window, but our popup window was blocked by your browser.  If you can disable the blocker temporarily, you'll be able to print here.  Sorry!");
    }
}-*/;
```

CSS File - StyleSheet.css

```
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 300%;
}
p  {
  color: red;
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 160%;
}
```

So, what is problem and where am I going wrong?

Comment: There's a double-dot in `html..append("<link href=\"StyleSheet.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">");`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo mistake. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Can you check in the source if your stylesheet is getting appended in `head` or not?

Comment: I am beginner, how to check the source and what should I find there?

Comment: If you mean  Inspect of web page, then I have the following there,

```<link href="InsightsStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">```

and the following error

```InsightsStyleSheet.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: Exactly, which means the stylesheet isn't being able to load itself. Kindly check the path that you're setting for it

Comment: Both the files are present in the same folder. So, I guess the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments you wrote:

> Both the files are present in the same folder. So, I guess the path is correct.

That's not true. You need to distinguish your *source* folder from *public* folder. It would be very unsafe if you could link files in *source* folder and make them available for download.

You should read about [Standard Directory and Package Layout](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions). There you'll find:

> **src folder** - contains production Java source
>
> **war folder** - your web app; contains static resources as well as compiled output

That means, that you need to put your `StyleSheet.css` file in the `war` folder.

After copying the `StyleSheet.css` file to the `war` folder (and fixing some typos in the code you've posted - see my edit) I got this as a proof that it works:

[image]

As further reading I suggest `Public Path` part of the [Modules: Units of configuration](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules) documentation.

---

After saying all the above: it would be much easier if you simply create a static html file in the `war` folder and open a new window with a link to this file as a parameter.